# Ladders on a rung, $1/2$ chance to go up and $1/2$ chance to go down, with a twist

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, markov-chains, conditional-probability

I am doing this problem here from the HMMT competition: https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/1999/feb/oral/solutions.pdf

> You are somewhere on a ladder with 5 rungs. You have a fair coin and an envelope that contains
> either a double-headed coin or a double-tailed coin, each with probability 1/2. Every minute you
> flip a coin. If it lands heads you go up a rung, if it lands tails you go down a rung. If you move
> up from the top rung you win, if you move down from the bottom rung you lose. You can open
> the envelope at any time, but if you do then you must immediately flip that coin once, after which
> you can use it or the fair coin whenever you want. What is the best strategy (i.e. on what rung(s)
> should you open the envelope)?

Here's the solution. I understand everything that follows and had independently come up with the same:

> First consider the probability of winning if you never open the envelope. Let $q(n)$ be the probability of winning from the nth rung with just the fair coin, then $q(n) = (q(n−1)+q(n+1))/2$, so it is not hard to calculate that $q(n) = n/6$. If we open the envelope, then there’s a $1/2$ chance that it is heads and we win, and a $1/2$ chance that it is tails and we end up one rung down with just the fair coin (obviously we keep using the double sided coin iff it is double headed). Let us start by analyzing rung $1$. If we don’t open the envelope, then we have a $1/2$ chance of losing and a $1/2$ chance of ending up on rung $2$ with the envelope. If we do open the envelope, then we have a $1/2$
> chance of losing and a $1/2$ chance of winning, which is a better outcome, so we should open the
> envelope on rung $1$. Next we look at rung $5$. If we don’t open the envelope, then we have a $1/2$
> chance of winning and a $1/2$ chance of moving down to rung $4$ with the envelope. If we do open
> the envelope, then we we have a $1/2$ chance of winning and a $1/2$ chance of moving down to rung
> $4$ without the envelope. Let $p(n)$ be the probability of winning from rung $n$ if we are there with
> the envelope still unopened. Then clearly $p(n) \ge q(n)$ for all $n$ if we’re using optimal strategy, so
> we should not open the envelope on rung $5$. Next we look at rung $4$. If we open the envelope,
> then our chance of winning is $1/2 + q(3)/2 = 3/4$. If we don’t, then our chance of winning is
> $p(5)/2 + p(3)/2$. We do know that $p(5) = 1/2 + p(4)/2$, but this is not enough to tell us what to
> do on rung $4$. Looking at rung $3$, we can open the envelope for a probability $1/2 + q(2)/2 = 2/3$ of
> winning, and we can not open the envelope for a probability $p(4)/2 + p(2)/2$ of winning. On rung
> $2$, we can open the envelope for a probability $1/2 + q(1)/2 = 7/12$ of winning, and we can not open
> the envelope for a probability $p(3)/2 + p(1)/2 = p(3)/2 + 1/4$ of winning.
>
> Now we can use all this information together for the complete answer.

However, I don't understand how any of the assertions in the next sentence follow from what's already been quoted.

> We know $p(2) \ge 7/12$,
> therefore $p(3)\ge p(4)/2 + 7/24$, and we know $p(4) \ge p(5)/2 + p(3)/2 \ge
> (1/2+p(4)/2)/2 + p(3)/2 \ge (1/2+p(4)/2)/2 + (p(4)/2+7/24)/2$.

I don't even understand how it follows that $p(2) \ge 7/12$, much less anything that follows. Can anyone help?

Comment: If opening the envelope has a 50% chance of giving you the double-headed coin, how could it ever be worse than tossing the fair coin?

Comment: @Karl: Think of it this way.  If the envelope has the double-headed coin, then you win no matter what since you will eventually open the envelope (and it doesn't matter when you do it).  So the decision of when to open the envelope only matters if it has the double-tailed coin, in which case opening it actually hurts your chances.  So if you're at the bottom rung you should open it because you need to make sure you open it before you lose, but at any other rung, you're better off putting off opening it until you fall to the bottom rung (because you have nothing to lose by doing so).

Comment: To put it another way, opening the envelope is strictly better than tossing the fair coin on each individual toss...but you only get to open the envelope once.  Not opening the envelope means you can save the chance to open it for a time that it might be *more* strictly better than tossing the fair coin, i.e. when you are on the bottom rung.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, $p(2)\geq 7/12$ follows immediately from the earlier statement

> On rung $2$, we can open the envelope for a probability $1/2 + q(1)/2 = 7/12$ of winning...

Then $p(3)\geq p(4)/2+7/24$ follows from

> Looking at rung $3$, ...we can not open the envelope for a probability $p(4)/2 + p(2)/2$ of winning.

since $p(3)\geq p(4)+p(2)/2$ and $p(2)\geq 7/12$.

Then $p(4)\geq p(5)/2+p(3)/2$ follows from

> Next we look at rung $4$... If we don’t, then our chance of winning is
> $p(5)/2 + p(3)/2$.

and the rest is just substituting in known values.

Comment: Thanks Eric. But  I don't see how $p(2) \ge 7/12$ immediately follows from $1/2 + q(1)/2 = 7/12$ (which was the entire point of me asking on MSE). Can you elaborate a bit on the reasoning there at the level of a verbal explanation?

Comment: By definition, $p(2)$ is the probability of winning from rung 2 using the optimal strategy.  One strategy you can use is to open the envelope immediately, and that gives you a 7/12 chance of winning, so $p(2)$ can't be worse than 7/12.